# Custom Xcode Simulator Device / Size (e.g. 20x5)

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, prototype, device, simulator

Ideally I would want to define my own Device for in the Simulator. Let's say 2000w x 500h.

**Anybody know of any way to accomplish this?**

You might be wondering, "why does he want to do that?" It's for prototyping, a non standard sized screen.

Some directions, but not sure if they can work:

- unlocking the aspect ratio of window resizing
- creating an own device
- changing the sizes of one of the existing devices

Comment: That is not a supported operation. You can copy and modify a simdevicetype profile but you're on your own. CoreSimulator will load profiles from /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles if you want to experiment.

Comment: @russbishop thanks for that idea, I can't seem to find where the sizes are stored